# python, for loop and list append

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to extract a part of a string and append it to a list (message).
But at the end, what I see is just one item appended (the last one) to the list. Below is my code. 
What am i doing wrong?

```
for item in all_text:
    message = []
    if len(item) < 2:
        continue
    else:
        m_temp = item.split(']')[1].split(':')
        if len(m_temp) <= 1:
            continue
        else:
            message.append(m_temp[1])
    print(len(message))
    print(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the `message = []`  above the for loop and align the two print with the For

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining `message` to be an empty list with each iteration of your `for` loop.  Therefore, all of your previous appends will be lost except for the one on the last iteration.

Try moving `message = []` to right before your `for` loop.

Comment: move the message = []  above the for loop and align the tow print with the For